# How can I add event listener when the page loaded using xul for the current tab only?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have tried: `window.addEventListener("load", function(){}, true)` and `content.document.defaultView.addEventListener("load", function(){}, true)` but both don't work.

Comment: Do you want to listen to "load" events of tabs? The browser window? The current tab? What exactly is your question? I guess the first, but guessing usually doesn't cut it.

Comment: I need to listen for the current tab only. I don't need the listener to be invoked for all the new tabs.

Comment: Edit your question please with this information.

Comment: This bootstrap template here uses the method given in solution by @nmaier: [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-template-BootstrapWatchHostEventListener.xpi](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9287185)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [tabbrowser snippets example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_page_load) verbatim (see my answer to your previous question):

```
function examplePageLoad(event) {
  if (event.originalTarget instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIDOMHTMLDocument) {
    var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;
    if (win.frameElement) {
      // Frame within a tab was loaded. win should be the top window of
      // the frameset. If you don't want do anything when frames/iframes
      // are loaded in this web page, uncomment the following line:
      // return;
      // Find the root document:
      win = win.top;
    }
  }
}

// do not try to add a callback until the browser window has
// been initialised. We add a callback to the tabbed browser
// when the browser's window gets loaded.
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  // Add a callback to be run every time a document loads.
  // note that this includes frames/iframes within the document
  gBrowser.addEventListener("load", examplePageLoad, true);
}, false);

...
// When no longer needed
gBrowser.removeEventListener("load", examplePageLoad, true);
...
```

1. First you wait for the browser top window to actually initialize (`window.addEventListener`).
2. Then you add your event listener for page loads in tabs (`gBrowser.addEventListener`).

So far, so good...

Now, we need to discard all events that aren't the current document/tab. We can just compare the `.originalTarget` against `content.document`.

Here is essentially the same code as above with said check (and a bit shorter):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  gBrowser.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
     if (event.originalTarget != content.document) {
       return;
     }
     // XXX do something
  }, true);
}, false);
```

You may want to implement not only a listener for `load` but also for [`pageshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pageshow) if necessary.

There is an alternative however, sparing the check (as documented in ["On page load"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load)). There were some problems with that IIRC, so I wouldn't recommend it, and you'd also need to filter out non-document loads (images, etc.) anyway.